# When I delete a file/folder on Windows in a Samba share - what unix commands are being issued?

Tags: command-line, unix, samba

Let's say I have a Samba share and a Windows client deletes a folder in it. Is it the same internally as `rm -rf foldername`? Is there any cleanup needed?

Also is there a difference for the Samba share if I do `shift+delete` like on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samba is a protocol that lets a user connect to an underlying file system over a network. So essentially the unix command `rm` tells the file system software to remove the link to the file.

So to give an example that answers your first question:

1. You click delete on your Windows computer
2. Windows' Samba service tells the Samba server to remove the file reference
3. The Samba server tells the file system to remove the reference
4. You get a confirmation that the file was removed, and therefore, it disappears in Windows Explorer.

And no, there's not anything like a 'Recycle Bin' in Samba. And under normal circumstances, don't expect that the server has a recycle bin either.

You can probably benefit from reading an [introduction to the SMB protocol](https://www.samba.org/cifs/docs/what-is-smb.html).